# How to removing multiple strings from a PostgreSQL string column

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PSQL database, I have the following table structure and I would like to understand how I can remove multiple strings from the `currentIds`and `totalIds`

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."candidates" (
    "day" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "study_id" varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    "site_id" varchar(32),
    "status" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "total" int4 NOT NULL,
    "current" int4 NOT NULL,
    "referrer_token" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO_REFERRER_TOKEN'::character varying,
    "total_ids" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '|'::text,
    "current_ids" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '|'::text
);
```

What I want to achieve is the following example.

I have for example:

```
current_ids: '|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-003|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|ABX1-006|'
total_ids: '|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-003|ABX1-004|ABX1-004|ABX1-006|ABX1-007|'
```

From those 2 columns, I want to remove the IDs: 'ABX1-003', 'ABX1-006', 'ABX1-007'

so the final result will be:

```
current_ids: '|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|'
total_ids: '|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-004|'
```

I tried so far something like this but didn't work

```
UPDATE
    candidates
SET
    "current_ids" = regexp_replace("current_ids", 'ABX1-003|ABX1-006|ABX1-007', '', 'g')
WHERE
    "current_ids" in('ABX1-003', 'ABX1-006', 'ABX1-007')
```

Comment: You can't use the WHERE IN, because that is expecting an exact match, current_ids does not equal 'ABX1-003' so Where IN would result in no reecords changed

Comment: You could use, WHERE "current_ids" like '%ABX1-003%' etc...

Comment: Don't store multiple values as delimited strings.

Comment: As @MatBailie suggests, it is a bad practice to store multiple values in delimited strings. If `current_ids` and `total_ids` are hold references to rows in other tables, then the design should be changed to use associative tables to maintain the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will only update rows with strings that will be changed:

```
WITH patterns(pattern) AS (
  VALUES ('(?<=\|)(ABX1-003|ABX1-006|ABX1-007)\|'))
UPDATE candidates
  SET current_ids = regexp_replace(current_ids, patterns.pattern, '', 'g'),
      total_ids = regexp_replace(current_ids, patterns.pattern, '', 'g')
  FROM patterns
  WHERE candidates.current_ids ~ patterns.pattern
     OR candidates.total_ids ~ patterns.pattern;
```

A single pattern is used to both select the rows that will be affected and to drive the regular expression replacement. The lookbehind, `(?<=\|)`, insures that each replacement match is preceded by a `|` delimiter without consuming the `|` by the match; thus, only full field matches will be found.